# Horizontal representation of v-data-table data

Tags: vue.js, vuetify.js, v-data-table

[Desired Results](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Y50tp.png)

Like a picture in a v-data-table.
Can I use rowspan to express it?

Or can you express the data like this if you change rows and columns using span?

ex) When an item in test1 receives a value for the item of the next person (test2), it is determined to be a new value and displayed on the next line.

Please let me know how to solve it.

[Current Progress](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cUVyY.png)

```html
<v-data-table
      sort-by="class"
      group-by="class"
      :group-desc="[true]"
      :headers="headers"
      :items="items"
      :search="search"
      :loading="loading"
      loading-text="Loading... Please wait"
      hide-default-footer
      class="elevation-1"
    >
     <!-- Modify Here
      <template #[`item.class`]="{ item }">
        <tr v-for="i in items" :key="i.class === 10">
          <td :rowspan="[items.length]">
            {{ item.name }}
          </td>
        </tr>
      </template>
-->
      <template #[`item.employee_avatar`]="{ item }">
        <v-img
          :src="require('@/' + item.imgsrc)"
          style="width: 100px; height: 100px"
        />
      </template>
      <template #[`item.name`]="{ item }">
        <a
          target="_blank"
          :href="`.../list:${item.name}`"
        >
          {{ item.name }}
        </a>
</template>
</v-data-table>
```

Comment: add the code that you tried

Comment: If your problem is to display multiple students of a class and you cant fit them in one cell.
Then save the length of students array of whatever the name of array is and then bind it with colspan so it will increase or decrease colspan accordingly

EXample 
col_count:'youraarray.length'
use in table
<tr :colspan="col_count"></tr>

Comment: Thank you for your answer.

If it's colspan, can it be expressed like the result picture?

Comment: You cannot specify a length value as many groups as the class criteria.